# the same process PID

Tags: node.js, express

I am really confusing. I've tried to start node server and after executing lsof -i:5000   I have the following.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4LX3.png)

That point on same PID and kill -9 1043 don't work. Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same process listens on ipv4 and ipv6 interfaces (same port 5000). It is ok.

Either it is restarted each time you kill it (PID will change in this case),
or you don't have permissions to kill processes of the user (should get "Operation not permitted")

Comment: thanks you, i figure out that macOS Monterey has a new feature called "AirPlay Receiver" that uses port 5000. OMG And i tried to kill it....